# How to ensure that ssh connection does not hang when connection is closed?

Tags: ssh, connection

I have problem that ssh session hangs when connection is closed due to network error (i.e., router is rebooted). With hang I mean that terminal does not respond to ^C or anything like that.

What is solution this kind of problems?

Comment: It may not matter, but are you using PUTTY?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS, but this looks relevant: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-ssh-server-connection-drops-out-after-few-or-n-minutes-of-inactivity.html